# Riddle — What am I?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

> While I am sleeping, I count four then forty then two hundred and forty.
>
> When I am awake, tiny Mickeys tremble.

**What am I?**

---

Hint 1:

> If I continued counting, two thousand four hundred would be next.

Hint 2:

> Hotel Hotel Oscar.

Hint 3:

> Mickey has a 104.5 degree fever.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: Pete in mickey mouse is mickey's enemy

Comment: Wrong bounty description, I meant to say "looking for a correct answer"

Comment: I promise that this has a very clear answer that will connect every single dot!

Comment: Can you explain the first line of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you a

> <s>water heater?</s> Microwave oven?

While I am sleeping, I count four then forty then two hundred and forty.

> You show a clock when turned off

When I am awake, tiny Mickeys tremble.

Mickey has a 104.5 degree fever.

> A microwave oven Vibrates water molecules in food and drinks when turned on
>  
>  
>  [Tiny Mickey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4GKY.gif)

Hotel Hotel Oscar.

> H20

Comment: Good guess! But not correct :)

Comment: @AustinA rot13(vf Ubgry Bfpne Bfpne. pbeerpg? Be vf vg Ubgry Ubgry Bfpne.)

Comment: I do not speak that language, so I cannot answer your question.

Comment: @AustinA rot13.com, paste the text there ;-)

Comment: !!! You're right, I'll update it.

Comment: updated my answer aswell :)

Comment: Not formatted very elegantly, but correct!

Comment: Yesterday was late, I've reformatted my answer.

Comment: I still don't get the 4 -> 40 -> 240 part?

Comment: It’s what happens when you want to cook something for 4 minutes, you enter 4-0-0 on the number pad. The clue could have also been 1 -> 10 -> 60 or 3 -> 30 -> 180

Comment: @AustinA this happens with ours, we can cook something for 98 seconds, 99 seconds, and then 60 seconds! It all makes sense now.

Comment: That got me thinking that it must be closer to a decade since I last saw a numeric keypad on one of those things, so of course I had to check a local retailer's catalogue: they actually DID have one model (out of the 49 in stock) that still had a numpad.

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> an owl?

I'm still working on "While I am sleeping, I count four then forty then two hundred and forty." and hint #1, which I'm assuming this is related to @filip's answer, and it's:

> 4 minutes, 40 minutes, 4 hours, and 40 hours

No idea how that ties in though

When I am awake, tiny Mickeys tremble.

> Owls hunt mice

Hint #2: Hotel Oscar Oscar

> Owls go 'hoo!'. Well, some do

Comment: Good guess, but nope!

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> [image: apple iwatch with mickey mouse clock face]

While I am sleeping, I am four then forty then two hundred and forty.

> In degrees you get the angle of the hour hand of a watch during normal sleeping hours (about 12 to 7). Watch is also inactive during this time.

When I am awake, tiny Mickeys tremble.

> Mickey is moving his hands when screen is active.

Comment: Close but no cigar!

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> An owl clock? [image: owl clock]

While I am sleeping, I count four then forty then two hundred and forty.

> What @filip said

When I am awake, tiny Mickeys tremble.

> The owls eyes typically move in these types of clocks, which would frighten mice.

Hint 2

> Hoo